# не срабатывает emit()

Tags: angular

Есть три компонента

Первый основной, второй вложен в первом, третий вложен во второй. Дочерний компонент общается с родительским с помощью eventEmitter.

При emit() в третьем компоненте во втором срабатывает функция и если в функции есть emit() события для первого компонента, то он уже не срабатывает. Как лучше поступить в данной ситуации?

Component 3:
html:

```
<mat-radio-group class="radio-group"                                
    (change)="statusChange.emit({e: $event, f: loadedPage, c: 
        contract.blankref.name})">
       <ng-container *ngFor="let status of fileStatus">
       <mat-radio-button 
           *ngIf="secondaryFilesStatus.includes(status.code)"
           [ngClass]="['radio-button', 
           filestatusColor[status.code].radio]"
           [checked]="compareStatuses(status, loadedPage.status)" 
           [matTooltip]="status.description"
           [value]="status">
           {{ status.title }}
       </mat-radio-button>
   </ng-container>
   </mat-radio-group>
```

ts:

```
@Output() statusChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

Component 2:

html:

```
<files-work>       
    [files]="files"
    (statusChange)="statusChangeEmit($event)">
</files-work>
```

ts:

```
@Output() saveDoc: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

statusChangeEmit(data) {
    this.openChangeDialog(data.e, data.f, data.c);
}



openChangeDialog(e, file, category) {
    const oldStatus = file.status ? 
    SharedService.copyObject(file.status) : false;
    file.status = SharedService.copyObject(e.value);
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
      width: '500px',
      height: 'auto',
      disableClose: true,
      data: {
        comment: true,
        title: 'Вы уверены?',           
      }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result && result.confirm) {
        file.status.comment = result.message;
        this.saveDoc.emit(); 
      } else {
        oldStatus ? file.status = oldStatus : delete file.status;
      }
    });
  }
```

Component 1:

html:

```
(saveDoc)="onSaveCard()"
```

ts:

```
onSaveCard() {
    try {
    console.log('save') // код не срабатывает при emit() в    
    компоненте 3
      this.dataTable.saveCard(false, false); 
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: что в вашем понятии "не срабатывает"? с чего вы взяли что `emit` возвращает `Promise` что применяете к нему `await`?

Comment: Не срабатывает, значит, что при этом ничего не происходит. await для emit действительно ни к чему.

Comment: приведите весь код, пока что, к сожалению, это гадание на гуще :( и знать почему оно не работает можно только гадать

Comment: привел весь код